# Symfony seems to register, but not trigger my doctrine event

Tags: symfony, orm, event-listener, symfony-3.4

sry if something is not so accurate, but im less experienced with Symfony

I have the following orm mapping:

```
src/app/ExampleBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Base.orm.yml

app\ExampleBundle\Entity\Base:
type: mappedSuperclass
fields:
    createdAt:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        options:
            default: null
    updatedAt:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        options:
            default: null
```

This creates a entity Base which i modified to be abstract

```
src/app/ExampleBundle/Entity/Base.php

abstract class Base {
    ...
}
```

I have some other entities they extend this abstract class e.g.

```
src/app/ExampleBundle/Entity/Category.php

class Category extends Base
{
    ...
}
```

Now i tried to add a listener that sets the createdAt/updatedAt datetime on every persist for every entity that extends the Base Entity

```
src/app/ExampleBundle/EventListener/BaseListener.php

namespace app\ExampleBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use app\ExampleBundle\Entity\Base;

class BaseListener
{
    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(Base $base, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $user = null;
        }

        if ($base->getCreatedAt() === null) {
            $base->setCreated($user, new \DateTime());
        } else {
            $base->setUpdated($user, new \DateTime());
        }
    }
}
```

And added it to the bundles services.yml

```
src/app/ExampleBundle/Resources/config

services:
    app\ExampleBundle\EventListener\BaseListener:
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: app\ExampleBundle\Entity\Base, event: prePersist }
```

Symfony throws no Exception, but the defined event seems also not triggered.

I tried to change the entity param in services to the "real" entity Category, but still no error, nor the event triggered.

I think, i did everything as it is decribed in the documentation. But it still not working.

The command

```
debug:event-dispatcher
```

does also not show the event

So, the question is: What did i wrong?

Comment: entity field, in tags, must refer to `Category`, not `Base`

Comment: @SilvioQ: 'I tried to change the entity param in services to the "real" entity Category, but still no error, nor the event triggered.'

Comment: What version of doctrine are you using? If its < 2.5 you need to specify the listener on the entity as well

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor: "^2.5". I tried to set the lifecycleCallbacks, but they try to trigger some method inside the entity

Comment: Did you try to set HasLifecycleCallbacks() insise the base entity?

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor: No, but the symsony doc says "This is not necessary if you're using YAML". I tried to define the lifecycleCallback in the orm.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, many more tests, diving into the EntityManager and the UnitOfWork. Nothing seems to work fine. I get it so far to work on `doctrine:fixtures:load`, but for any reason they still not working if i use the entity manager in the Controllers. So, i decided to try another way with a subscriber.

```
tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }

class ... implements EventSubscriber
```

So i still dont know why the Listener did not work as expected, but with the subscribers i found a solution that does.

Thanks to all of you for support :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the documentation I follow https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

The prePersist method is called for all the entities so you must exclude non instance of app\ExampleBundle\Entity\Base. The first argument is LifecycleEventArgs.

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $base = $event->getObject();
    if (!$base instanceof Base) {
        return;
    }
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        $user = null;
    }

    if ($base->getCreatedAt() === null) {
        $base->setCreated($user, new \DateTime());
    } else {
        $base->setUpdated($user, new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

I can recommend you [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) (Timestampable) that does exactly what you want. It based on [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions).

There is even a [trait](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/timestampable.md#traits) that works like a charm.

Comment: Where does `$args` come from?

Comment: My Problem is that the prePersist Method does never run. I tried to throw Exception or die() inside the prePersist method, but nothing is called.

And thanks for Link to the StofBundle, i will take a look at it.

Comment: May be, you must change the tag name to `doctrine.event_listener` (without orm). `entity` property is not necesary.

Comment: @SilvioQ +1 I missed the tag name

Comment: @SilvioQ: I have already tried the `doctrine.event_listener`, also to set a real entity, omit the entity, set the class param. But nothing seems to trigger the event -.-

Comment: Your service must look like this  `          - { name: doctrine.entity_listener, event: prePersist }` . I think console debug:event-dispatcher command does not show doctrine events.

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 5 and anybody who will struggle with issue when Events::loadClassMetadata is not fired in subscriber.

Class should implement "EventSubscriberInterface"

```
class DiscriminatorSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [Events::loadClassMetadata];
}

public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $event): void
{

}
```

Than you dont have to do anythng more if you have autoconfigure and autowire on TRUE in your services.yml

Doctrine will handle your subscriber registration (check DoctrineExtension.php)

```
 $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(EventSubscriberInterface::class)
        ->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber');
```